# What is the most comfortable datatype I can use to populate a DropDownList with?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, drop-down-menu

For example, I want a user to create a new fanclub for a given Team.

Obviously the teams have to be loaded into a DropDownList so they are chosen from a pre-set choice group. The list of teams are returned from a database.

As of now I'm doing things like this:

```
//FindAll() returns IQueryable<Team>
var Teams = teamsRepo.FindAll().AsEnumarable();
myDropDownList.DataTextField = "Name";
myDropDownList.DataValueField = "ID";
myDropDownList.DataSource = Teams;
myDropDownList.DataBind();
```

Unfortunately when doing things this way I have no strongly typed attributes, so there is a risk of misspelling the ValueField or TextField.

There is also a problem when trying to get the selected value of the DropDownList. Using the following code, everything is saved with ID 1 regardless of what team was chosen.

```
fansite.IDTeam = myDropDownList.SelectedIndex;
```

Any suggestions on how to improve?

Comment: Is this ASP.NET? If so, is ViewState enabled on the Page / DropDownList?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is exactly how .NET databinding works, you have to type in the property names.

You could always add a converter to a combobox item and then call add ([ms-doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.objectcollection.add.aspx))

As far as getting the value of the selected item try this:

```
fansite.IDTeam = myDropDownList.SelectedValue;
```

Answer (score 2):

From your question it seems you're concerned about the hard coded strings for the databinding in your code.  The same thing used to drive me nuts too.

There is a good way of using lambda methods and expression trees that will allow you to get rid of the hard coded strings and get the property names in a strongly typed way:

You can use this class and extension method...

```
public class Nameof<T>
{
    public static string Property<TProp>(Expression<Func<T, TProp>> expression)
    {
        var body = expression.Body as MemberExpression;
        if(body == null)
            throw new ArgumentException("'expression' should be a member expression");
        return body.Member.Name;
    }
}
```

...and this will allow you to do the following:

```
//instead of myDropDownList.DataTextField = "Name";
myDropDownList.DataTextField = Nameof<Team>.Property(t => t.Name);
//instead of myDropDownList.DataValueField = "ID";
myDropDownList.DataValueField = Nameof<Team>.Property(t => t.ID);
```

That's what I like to see; not a hard coded string literal in sight! :-)

Comment: Reflection is slow, IMO this is a solution to a non-problem which just slows down the code and makes it more obtuse.

Comment: Yes reflection is slow, but expression trees do not use reflection.

Comment: Ah, point taken -- I see now it happens in the compiler; mea culpa.

Answer (score 1):

(This was written before the ASP.Net clarification, I have answered from a winforms persepective).

I'm not sure what your `Teams` IDs are like, but if they are not sequential, zero based and with no gaps, using `myDropDownList.SelectedIndex;` will give you the wrong piece of data.

I think you last line should read:

```
fansite.IDTeam = myDropDownList.SelectedValue;
```

On the data type to use, I usually use a `Dictionary<int, string>` for dropdown lists, and have a few helper extension methods to make population a little nicer.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using DataSources like `ObjectDataSource` or `LinqDataSource` to DataBind your controls.

It will save you time and is less error prone because you will configure your settings through a wizard instead of defining them in your code-behind.